# EPPlus - Creata a new file, Formula remaining same in all rows when source data is in the datatable

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, epplus-4

I want to create a copy of a excel file [p.xlsx]. It has two spreadsheets - sheet1 and sheet2. I create another file perror.xlsx by using p.xlsx as a template file.

Sheet1 data is as follows (second column has a formula):

> COL1, COl2
>
> MICK1,=A2
>
> MICk2,=A3

The data in the Sheet1 is defined as a table - Table1 =$A:$B

Sheet2 is "not defined" as a table, the data again is same

> COL1, COl2
>
> MICK1,=A2
>
> MICk2,=A3

Executed the code as follows:

```
string ErrFileName = @"C:\\TEMP\\pErrors.xlsx";  //Destination file
FileInfo errorFile = new FileInfo(ErrFileName);

string templatefile = @"C:\\TEMP\\p.xlsx";   //Source file
FileInfo template = new FileInfo(templatefile);

ExcelPackage errorExcelFile = new ExcelPackage(errorFile, template);

errorExcelFile.Save();
errorExcelFile.Dispose();
```

When I open the perror.xlsx file, I see the data in the sheet1 as

> COL1, COl2
>
> MICK1,MICK1
>
> MICk2,MICK1

Analyzed the formula so it was found as:

> COL1, COl2
>
> MICK1,=A2
>
> MICk2,=A2

But the sheet2 was populated properly.

> COL1, COl2
>
> MICK1,MICK1
>
> MICk2,MICK2

So does that mean the EPPLUS does not bring the formula correctly when the data is in the table?

I could bring the data correctly in the sheet1 only when in the source file I opened it in excel clicked on sheet1, visited Design menu, convert to range, saved.

Let me know please how to bring the data correctly when the formula is in a table?

Comment: You simply want to copy the file without modifying it? Why do you need EPPlus to do that? Why not simply `System.IO.File.Copy`?

Comment: Hi Mason, thanks. I know that is the workaround but want to know why the above approach isn't working? Why it gets messed up - when it uses the original file as a template file. Thanks.

Comment: Even copying the file does not help as this file need to be opened using EPPlus and then manipulation need to be done in the same worksheets, when saved the formula anyhow gets messed up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain I understand what you are tryign to achieve but you could just use `SaveAs()`:

```
string ErrFileName = @"C:\\TEMP\\pErrors.xlsx";  //Destination file
FileInfo errorFile = new FileInfo(ErrFileName);

string templatefile = @"C:\\TEMP\\p.xlsx";   //Source file
FileInfo template = new FileInfo(templatefile);

ExcelPackage templateFile = new ExcelPackage(template);
templateFile.SaveAs(errorFile);
errorExcelFile.Dispose();
```

(As an aside - it is normal to wrap an `IDisposable` in a `using{}` block rather than explicitly calling `.Dispose()` - your code, your decision though)

Comment: Thanks Stewart, just a raw working  test code was pasted here.

Answer (score 0):

When the data was in a table, the formula need to be changed in the COL2

```
COL1, COl2

MICK1,=[COL1]

MICk2,=[COL1]
```

It brought the correct result.